# clock_nanosleep does not return -1 / set errno EINTR - LINUX

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, posix, clock

I am a Linux newbie. I am trying to implement a simple task using clock_nanosleep. The issue is, clock_nanosleep is not setting errno to EINTR after interrupted by the signal. I have tried resetting SA_RESTART flag. But, no success. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
void signalHandler( int signum )
{
    printf("Interrupt signal received.\n");
}

void *periodic_thread (void *param)
{
struct itimerspec its;
struct sigevent sig;
struct timespec next, period;
sigset_t blocked;

siginfo_t si;
timer_t mytimer;
int i, j;

/* create a timer that will be used to periodically send a signal */
sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
sig.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;
sig.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &sig;

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig, &mytimer);

struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = &signalHandler;
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

/* set the periodic timer */
its.it_value.tv_sec = 8;
its.it_value.tv_nsec = 00000000; 
its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0; ;
period.tv_sec = 5;
period.tv_nsec = 00000000; 

timer_settime(mytimer, 0, &its, NULL); 

printf("periodic thread started...\n");

j=1;

i = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &next);
while(1)
{
  next.tv_sec = next.tv_sec + period.tv_sec;
  next.tv_nsec = next.tv_nsec + period.tv_nsec;
  i = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &next, 0);  
  printf("I am done \n");
  if((i == -1) && (errno == EINTR))
  break;
}

printf("...periodic thread end!\n");

timer_delete(mytimer);
return NULL;
}

int main()
{

  pthread_t mythread;
  pthread_attr_t myattr;

  //struct sched_param myparam;
  void *returnvalue;
  sigset_t blocked;


  /* initializes the thread attribute */
  pthread_attr_init(&myattr);


  printf("starting a periodic thread...\n");

  pthread_create(&mythread, &myattr, periodic_thread, NULL);

  pthread_attr_destroy(&myattr);

  /* wait the end of the thread we just created */
  pthread_join(mythread, &returnvalue);

  printf("ending main...\n");

return 0;
}
```

Output>>

```
  starting a periodic thread...
  periodic thread started...
  I am done 
  Interrupt signal received.
  I am done 
  I am done
  continues.. (Does not break the while(1))
```

Comment: Destroying the attributes before the thread has necessarily had a chance to read it is probably not a good idea. Swap the destroy and join operations.  Or use default attributes (pass a null pointer to `pthread_create()`) since you aren't setting any non-default attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue,

Issue: Main thread was getting interrupted by a signal instead of child thread consisting clock_nanosleep.

Solution 1: Block SIGUSR1 in main thread using "pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &blocked, NULL)"

Solution 2: Generate thread specific events using "sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID". (Works for timers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most traditional system calls, `clock_nanosleep` does not return -1 on failure. According to [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_nanosleep.html#tag_03_77_04):

> If the clock_nanosleep() function returns because it has been
>   interrupted by a signal, it shall return the corresponding error
>   value.

So try checking to see if it returns `EINTR`.

(Newer POSIX interfaces tend to return error codes instead of relying on `errno`. Somebody's idea of being more modern and thread-safe, I guess. Ultimate result is just a mess, though, IMO.)

Comment: I have already verified that. Here is the output:            starting a periodic thread...
periodic thread started...
I am done .. Return Value:0 
Interrupt signal received.
I am done .. Return Value:0 
I am done .. Return Value:0 
I am done .. Return Value:0